# Recurring event issue

Tags: mysql

i don't know there are already posted this type of question or not but i am unable to find my solution anywhere.

i am calculating date by this method

```
SELECT date(DATE_ADD('2012-9-12',INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,'2012-9-12',now()) month)) as date;
```

but here is some problem let me explain you that

this will output **'2012-11-12'** but this date is gone so i want output greater than current date that is **'2012-12-12'**

in general i always output greater than current date

please ask if have any queries

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you're not referencing any stored data, perhaps MySQL is the wrong tool for this job?
2. Your expression will *always* return a date less than or equal to the current date.  If you always want output *greater* than the current date you would have to add an additional month to the interval:

   ```
   SELECT date(DATE_ADD(
            '2012-9-12',
            INTERVAL 1 + TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,'2012-9-12',now()) month
          )) as date;
   ```